# How to call variables that were passed during execution time to another bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

Bash Script 1:

Asks for user name and hostname and stores to another variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter hostname:"
read hostname

echo -n "Enter the username"
read username

echo -n "enter the password:"
read -s password
```

: ' (I want to use spawn command before ssh , hence, I have written another script with expect as interpreter.
I want to pass the details entered by user to script 2)
'
Bash script 2:

```
#!/bin/expect

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname

expect {
         timeout
                { send_user "\nTimeout Exceeded - Check Host\n"; exit 1 }
         eof
                { send_user "\nSSH Connection To $hostname Failed\n"; exit 1 }
        incorrect
                {send_user "invalid password or account\n"; exit 1}

        "*assword:"
                { send "$password\n" }
expect "$"
interact
        }
```

: '
(but, how to invoke the information asked by script 1 during runtime to the script 2?) '

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 2):

You bash script will invoke the expect script like this:

```
expect script.exp "$username" "$password" "$hostname"
```

And the expect script will start like:

```
#!/bin/expect

lassign $argv username password hostname

# or if your version of expect is old and does not have "lassign"
# foreach {username password hostname} $argv break

# or, if you prefer
# set username [lindex $argv 0]
# set password [lindex $argv 1]
# set hostname [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$hostname
# etc etc
```

The `@` character has no special meaning, so it does not need an escape.

---

There is a security risk with the above approach: while the expect code is running, `ps` output will show the password.

You could share the password through the environment:

bash

```
export username password hostname
expect script.exp
```

expect

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $env(username)@$env(hostname)
# etc etc
```